# Issues with AVR atmega32a

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmel

I'm following this tutorial: http://pdp11.byethost12.com/AVR/ArduinoAsProgrammer.htm
I saw elsewhere, and I simply can't get it to work. I've connected the 10,11,12,13 pins exactly as shown in the schematic in said tutorial, checking and double checking and triple checking that I have it right.

Here's the message that pops up, using avrdude:
[image]

Now, after removing the MOSI/MISO/RESET/SCR pins, here's my connection scheme:

[image]

As it is, what happens is that the LED, that's connected to a random pin, lights up in a chaotic fashion, if I touch a circuit in a certain way or move a certain wire, it changes how much it lights.

Another thing is that the chip heats up quite a bit, just by setting the voltages and grounds.

So, I don't think my atmega32a (http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8155.pdf) is behaving as it should. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be going wrong and on what I can do to make avrdude recognize the chip??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need a ground connetion on pin 11, and Vcc on pin 10.  You should also have a couple of 0.1 uF bypass capacitors between Vcc and ground near the chip's power and ground connections (and perhaps a 10 uF or larger electrolytic cap between power and ground).

Comment: Sorry, in the picture I had removed the VCC on 10 as an experiment, but the led still lights up and the chip still heats up when it's off and the avcc pin on 30 is on.

When I remove the 11 VCC pin, the led lights up lower. When I remove both, the led turns off.

Comment: @triplebig, Peter is right you need a few decoupling capacitors between Vcc and GND. Also make sure your Vcc is stable 5V with no more than 100mV or ripple (100mV is still too much but micro supports plus/minus 5V). Also what Debugger are you using? Another thing that I can see from the picture above, what pins is your 16MHz crystal on micro connnected to?

Comment: @triplebig, instead of a picture a Schematic would be nice